# How to change hamburger color inside a fragment?

Tags: java

I want to change the color of the hamburger inside my home fragment.

my main activity code is

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

         actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);

        //actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you possibly check how to ask questions on SA? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

It would be perfect if you can show what you tried which resources you looked through, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create public func. in your activity.

```
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //.....
}

public void setToolbarIconColor(){
     Drawable drawable = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
     int tint = Color.parseColor("#FF0000"); // color red
     PorterDuff.Mode mode = PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP;
     drawable.setColorFilter(tint,mode);
     toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable);
}
```

And call activity func. as you wish

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    //.....

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setToolbarIconColor();
    }
}
```